# Zusammengesetztes Substantiv, welches stabil ist unter der Vertauschung der Substantive?

Tags: single-word-request, synonym, compound, curiosity

Ich suche nach einem zusammengesetzten Substantiv, welches gleichbedeutend bleibt, wenn man die beiden Komponenten miteinander austauscht (und eventuell eine Bezeichnung für solche Wörter, falls es eine gibt).

Ich weiß, dass es für Fantasie-Mischwesen relativ einfach machbar ist, zum Beispiel ist die Unterscheidung zwischen einem Bärmenschen und einem Menschbär nicht wirklich fundamental durch die deutsche Sprache gegeben (auch wenn man in manchen Geschichten da Unterschiede findet). Aus dem Englischen kennt man allerdings diesbezüglich in der Taxonomie die Unterscheidung zwischen *dog-bear* und *bear-dog*, welche sich interessanterweise nicht auf die gleiche ausgestorbene Tierart beziehen.

Ich fand außerdem noch Wörter wie *Hirnstamm* und *Stammhirn,* aber nach ein bisschen Recherche gibt es zwischen diesen beiden Wörtern doch Unterschiede.

Daher dachte ich, ich würde die Frage mal an euch wenden und vielleicht kennt ihr ja ein oder ein paar Wörter, die diese Eigenschaft erfüllen?

Comment: Das erscheint mir relativ aussichtslos, da im Deutschen das letztgenannte Teilsubstantiv eines zusammengesetzten Substantivs vorgibt, um was es sich tatsächlich handelt. Würdest du nach dreiteiligen Substantiven suchen, gäbe es hingegen unzählige Beispiele. Klassisch: Lutschfruchtbonbon oder Fruchtlutschbonbon? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpkGQUqnotg

Comment: Du glaubst also wirklich, dass es in der gesamten deutschen Sprache kein solches Beispiel gibt? Ich glaube auch, dass es schwer ist sowas zu finden, aber als aussichtslos würde ich es nicht bezeichnen. Ist Schokoladentafel und Tafelschokolade etwas verschiedenes? Möglicherweise, aber es gibt zumindest viele Wörter die dem von mir gesuchten sehr nahe kommen.

Comment: Eine *Schokoladentafel* ist hauptsächlich eine Tafel (ein flaches Ding), und erst in zweiter Linie Schokolade, während *Tafelschokolade* hauptsächlich Schokolade ist und erst in zweiter Linie ein flaches Ding. Und so versteht das jeder.

Comment: Eigennamen sind auch Substantive und damit erfüllt der Stadtname Baden-Baden deine Kriterien. Ich denke dass es auch in der Chemie einige Stoffe geben könnte die  es tun,

Comment: Funktionieren tut's einigermaßen bei Komposita, die eine Tautologie oder ein Oxymoron darstellen - Dabei dreht sich meistens der Sinn nicht um, wenn man das Kompositum umdreht, z.B *Hassliebe* und *Liebeshass*, *Ausnahmeregel* und *Regelausnahme*  (zugegebenermassen alles nicht sehr gebräuchlich)

Comment: In der Linguistik nennt man so etwas *copulative compound* - ein Kompositum, dessen beide Bestandteile beide semantisch Phasenkerne sind (z.B. *slave girl* oder *Dichterfürst*). Unter dieser Bezeichnung findet eine Web-Suche auch deutsche Beispiele.

Comment: @KilianFoth Ein *Dichterfürst* ist aber schon was anderes als ein *Fürstendichter*

Comment: Mitbürger mit Migrationshintergrund werden (leider) häufig nicht als bspw. _Italodeutsche_, sondern als _Deutschitaliener_ bezeichnet.

Comment: @Crissov Wenn man den Standpunkt der Wikipedia zu [Russlanddeutsche vs. Deutschrussen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russlanddeutsche#Begriffliche_Assoziationen) sinngemäß anwendet, wäre aber _Deutschitaliener_ tatsächlich passender, während _Italodeutsche_ eher in Richtung _Südtiroler_ zielen würde.

Comment: Ein Bärmensch ist ein Mensch. Ein Menschbär ist ein Bär. Der Hirnstamm ist der (seiner Form nach) Stamm des Hirns. Das Stammhirn ist der (wie man einst annahm) älteste Teil des Gehirns (denke an "Abstammung").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Wort [Tiefenschärfe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tiefenschaerfe) bedeutet laut Duden [Schärfentiefe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schaerfentiefe), und auch bei [Wikipedia ist man der Meinung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%A4rfentiefe), dass die beiden Wörter oft synonym gebraucht werden.

Wenn Du also darüber hinwegsehen kannst, dass Tiefenschärfe in der Optik noch eine [zweite Bedeutung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbildungstiefe) hat, nämlich "Abbildungstiefe", und dass Fotografie-Puristen vielleicht der Meinung sind, dass nur *Schärfentiefe* "richtig" ist, dann hast Du ein Wortpaar, wie Du es suchst.

**Update:**
Ein weiteres Paar einander synonymer Begriffe bilden [*Maßband*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maszband) und [*Bandmaß*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bandmasz). Der Duden dokumentiert das recht originell dadurch, dass er als Beispiel zu *Maßband* anführt:

> um den Hals der Näherin hängt das Maßband

und bei *Bandmaß* das Bild eines ebensolchen Nähstuben-Utensils einblendet. Aber auch im Heim- und Handwerkerbereich werden aufrollbare Längenmessvorrichtungen unter beiden Namen geführt.

Comment: Klingt vielversprechend. Ich werde die verschiedenen Bedeutungen mal recherchieren und sehen ob ich das durchgehen lasse. Vielen Dank für den Hinweis!

Comment: Dass Wörter synonym gebraucht werden, heißt nicht, dass sie auch synonym sind. Laien benutzen Fachbegriffe häufig falsch, deshalb haben diese noch lange nicht die angenommene Bedeutung. Tiefenschärfe und Schärfentiefe sind genausowenig dasselbe wie rechts und links – egal wie oft manche Menschen das miteinander verwechseln.

Comment: Auch ein Maßband und ein Bandmaß sind in ihrer Konnotation nicht gleich. Das Maßband ist ein Band, das zum Messen benutzt wird. Der Fokus liegt hier auf der Beschaffenheit des Maßes. Das Bandmaß dagegen setzt sich von anderen Längenmessgeräten ab, es verweist also auf die Kategorie der Längenmessgeräte. Wenn du dir einen Korpus anschaust (z.B. DWDS), wirst du feststellen, dass beide Begriffe überwiegend in unterschiedlichen Kontexten auftauchen, sie sind also nicht ohne weiters austauschbar.

Answer (score -1):

Das Begriffspaar "Hügelgrab" und "Grabhügel" dürfte den Kriterien entsprechen, zumindest spricht dieser Eintrag in der deutschen Wikipedia dafür: [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hügelgrab](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCgelgrab)

Auch hier kann man argumentieren, dass ein Grabhügel einen Hügel mit einem Grab darin bezeichnet, während ein Hügelgrab ein Grab in Form eines Hügels ist. Entscheidend ist, dass beide Varianten in der Praxis austauschbar zur Bezeichnung der gleichen Sache verwendet werden.

Nennen würde ich so ein Wort wohl ein parataktisches Kompositum oder Kopulativkompositum. Zu deren Merkmalen gehört laut [dieser Quelle](https://www.linguistik.hu-berlin.de/de/institut/professuren/korpuslinguistik/lehre/alte_jahrgaenge/ws-2003/hs-phaenomene-deutsch/pdf/PhaenomeneReferatFugenElementeZusammenfassung.pdf) das folgende:

> Die [unmittelbaren Konstituenten] sind ohne semantische und strukturelle Veränderungen vertauschbar

Comment: Einen *Grabhügel* kann es auf jedem Friedhof geben - *Hügelgräber* eher nicht.

Comment: fachlich müsste man da wohl einen Archäologen dazu befragen. Immerhin werden beide Wörter als Synonyme geführt, z.B. [hier](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/edit/1118)

Comment: @tofro Das Problem ist letztlich, dass _Grabhügel_ mehrere Bedeutungen hat, siehe z.B. im [Deutschen Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=grabhuegel). Am gängigsten ist heute der Erdhaufen auf einem frischen Grab, der natürlich mit Hügelgrab _nicht_ synonym ist. Wenn aber vom Kontext her klar ist, dass es um Archäologie bzw. große, alte Grabanlagen geht, dann könnten die Begriffe tatsächlich austauschbar sein. So hat es wohl auch der verlinkte WP-Artikel gemeint: "Grabhügel haben Höhen von 1 m bis über 30 m oder mehr".

Comment: @Matthias Erm, nein. Ein *Grabhügel* hat nicht mehrere Bedeutungen, sondern er ist ein (zumindestens außerhalb der Fachsprache) ein Oberbegriff für alles, was mit Grab und einem Hügel drumrum oder obendrüber zu tun hat - vom Erdhäufchen über einem Hamstergrab von Kindern bis zum Hügel, in dem sich eine ganze ägyptische Pyramide verbirgt. Dieser allgemeine Begriff ist in der Archäologie ein **Fachbegriff**, den der Archäologe, der sich eher selten mit Hamstergräbern beschäftigt, für das verwendet, was der Rest der Welt als *Hügelgrab* (also eine historische Grabstätte in einem Hügel) bezeichnet

Comment: +++ der Umgangssprachler sieht ein Hügelgrab grundsätzlich als historische Grabstätte, während ein Grabhügel einfach "Erde auf einem Grab" darstellt - siehe dazu auch die Diskussionsseite zum *Hügelgrab* und die (äußerst spaßige) Änderungshistorie dieser Seite auf Wikipedia, die sehr oft nur die Begrifflichkeiten gewechselt hat.