# Zusammensetzung von Adjektiv und Substantiv?

Tags: compound

Mich würde interessieren, wie Zusammensetzungen von Adjektiv und Substantiv im Deutschen funktionieren, und ob die Regel da anders sind als bei der Zusammensetzung von nur Substantiven.

Zum Beispiel: "Großteil" (großer Teil), "Kleinkind" (kleines Kind).

Darf man selbst neue solche Zusammensetzungen vornehmen?

Comment: "Darf man selbst neue solche Zusammensetzungen vornehmen?" Ich vermute, man darf, aber mir fällt kein sinnvolles Beispiel ein, wo mir die Zusammensetzung nicht bereits bekannt ist. Außerdem ist Vorsicht geboten, weil einige dieser Zusammensetzungen andere Bedeutungen haben, als man vermuten könnte. So ist z.B. ein Altvater nicht etwa ein alter Vater sondern ein Ururgroßvater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Darf man selbst neue solche Zusammensetzungen vornehmen?

Ja, das darf man (fast immer im Deutschen).
Es muss halt bildhaft und allgemein verständlich sein.

Dabei muss man aber etwas aufpassen:

- Es gibt viele Orts-, Eigennamen und *"etablierte"* Substantive die auf diese Weise gebildet werden, z.B.:

  - *[Altheim](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altheim_(M%C3%BCnster))* (Ortsname)
  - *[Großbritannien](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gro%C3%9Fbritannien)*
  - *[Kleinschmidt](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=kern&from=wb&h=1&q=Kleinschmidt)* (Eigenname)
  - *[Altvater](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Altvater)* (Danke [@Roland](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/60591/zusammensetzung-von-adjektiv-und-substantiv#comment146262_60591))
  - *[Großmutter](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gro%C3%9Fmutter)*
  - *[Kleinvieh](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kleinvieh)* (Danke [@phipsgabler](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/60591/zusammensetzung-von-adjektiv-und-substantiv#comment146265_60596))
  - etc.

  Wenn man der Meinung ist, einen neuen Begriff dieser Art erfunden zu haben, besteht die Gefahr Missverständnisse zu herauf zu beschwören (es sei denn Zweideutigkeit im Kontext ist gewünscht, ein beliebtes Stilmittel der Satire).
- Es gibt Bildungsregeln:

  - Die flektierte Endung des Adjektivs entfällt

    - *kleines Zeug* => *das Klein<strike>**[es]**</strike>zeug*
      *das kleine Zeug* => *das Klein<strike>**[e]**</strike>zeug*
    - *freies Zeichen* => *das Frei<strike>**[es]**</strike>zeichen*
      *das freie Zeichen* => *das Frei<strike>**[e]**</strike>zeichen*
    - *großer König* => *der Groß<strike>**[er]**</strike>könig*
      *der große König* => *der Groß<strike>**[e]**</strike>könig*
    - *die kleine Mutter* => *die Klein<strike>**[e]**</strike>mutter*
    - *grüner Tee* => *der Grün<strike>**[er]**</strike>tee*
      *der grüne Tee* => *der Grün<strike>**[e]**</strike>tee*
  - Das zusammengesetzte Substantiv wird immer groß- und zusammengeschrieben

---

Beispiele neuzeitlicher Wortbildungen:

- [Freiton](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rufzeichen)
- [Rotverschiebung](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rotverschiebung)
- [Kaltverschweißen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaltverschwei%C3%9Fen)
- [Blauhelm](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Blauhelm)
- [Rotarmist](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rotarmist)
- [Klarspüler](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Klarsp%C3%BCler)
- [*etc. ...*](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/60605/edit)

---

Weiterführende Links:

- *[Zusammenschreibung von Substantivverbindungen](https://journalismusausbildung.de/zusammenschreibung-von-substantivverbindungen)*
- *[Der Horror mit den substantivischen Zusammensetzungen](https://www.korrekturen.de/sprachleben/rechtschreibung/der_horror_mit_den_substantivischen_zusammensetzungen.shtml)*
- *[Zusammengesetzte Nomen, Adjektive und Verben](https://www.gut-erklaert.de/deutsch/zusammengesetzte-nomen.html)*

Verwandte Fragen auf German Language:

- *[Is Lebenslangeschicksalsschatz a possible correct composite word?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/59299/is-lebenslangeschicksalsschatz-a-possible-correct-composite-word)*
- *[Can I use a noun to describe another noun in German as in English?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18253/can-i-use-a-noun-to-describe-another-noun-in-german-as-in-english)*
  -*[Are there any restrictions to compound nouns formation?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46727/are-there-any-restrictions-to-compound-nouns-formation?rq=1)*
- *[Zusammengesetztes Substantiv, welches stabil ist unter der Vertauschung der Substantive?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34744/zusammengesetztes-substantiv-welches-stabil-ist-unter-der-vertauschung-der-subs)*
- *[Is there a longest German word?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32293/is-there-a-longest-german-word)*

Comment: Ich bin nicht sicher, ob das erste Beispiel gut passt, denn die Stadt schreibt sich [Groß-Gerau](https://www.gross-gerau.de/). Wenn es Südhessen sein soll, wäre [Altheim](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altheim_(M%C3%BCnster)) eine Möglichkeit.

Comment: @Henning Danke. Ich korrigiere das.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen die *Gelbwesten*, obwohl das französische Original *Gilets jaunes* eher eine Übersetzung als *Gelbe Westen* nahelegt. Trotzdem hat sich *Gelbwesten* weitgehend durchgesetzt. Vielleicht in Analogie zu Begriffen wie *Rotröcke* (Bezeichnung für britische Soldaten, als sie noch rote Uniformen trugen) oder *Blaumann* (blaue Arbeitskleidung).

Comment: @RHa Danke, Du inspirierst mich :)

Answer (score 1):

Die Konstruktion ist semi-produktiv.

Man kann von einem Blauteppich sprechen statt einem blauen Teppich, und der Sinn wird verstanden werden. Die Ausdrucksweise wird aber merklich als ungewöhnlich empfunden werden, weil so viele andere vergleichbere Begriffe subtil andere als die kompositionale Bedeutung haben.

Kurt Kusenberg spricht z.B. in einer seiner "Seltsamen Geschichten" von einer Schaustellerin, die eine "Kleinkuh" besitzt. Obwohl das Tier genau das ist, was der Name besagt - eine ungewöhnlich kleine Kuh - wirkt der Begriff doch unerwartet und trägt zur märchenhaften Atmosphäre bei (was in den Seltsamen Geschichten durchweg gewollt ist).

Comment: _Kleinkuh_ ist ja vielleicht noch in Analogie zu _Kleinvieh_ gebildet.